# How to detect whether KeyEvent is fired by Physical user or Remote user

Tags: user-interface, javafx, remote-access

I'm writing a Chat Box GUI using javafx for my Company. They use this application during Software Installation from a Remote Administrator in Windows 7 Enterprise.

**During installation, both are going to see the same screen.**

Consider either the User or Remote Administrator is typing in the TextField. Is it possible to detect whether that KeyEvent comes from the User's Keyboard (or) from the Remote Administrator's Keyboard in javafx?

If not possible in javafx, is it any other Language?

Comment: One thing you can do is make the Admin/Users app with a little difference. All the Admin apps can have an ID of admin and the Users app can have and ID of User. So just create two apps with one difference and that's the ID of the textbox.

Comment: Another thing you can do is have sign ins. Each sign can have a type admin or User.

Comment: It is definitely logical (and security-wise correct) to implement some login and credential subsystem if your system is designed to be used by different groups of users, especially each group of users has different access rights and use cases.